# C# - Simplest Way of Sorting Data by State then City

Tags: c#, sorting

So I have a List in C# in a format like this:

```
List<String> city_state = new List<String>();
//assume that each element in the above list has the following format:
```

- Oklahoma City,Oklahoma
- Boston,Massachusetts
- Indianapolis,Indiana
- Ab,A
- Aa,B
- etc

My idea was to use .Split(",") then call .Sort() on each List. The problem is, the cities won't reference it's corresponding state, thus corrupting the data. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: What is this exactly? Is it `string`? Is it `List<string>`? Be more specific. And please provide show but complete program demonstrating your problem as well.

Comment: I believe I added the appropriate details. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the strings in a `List<string> strings`, you can obtain a sorted list with some LINQ code:

```
var sortedList = strings
    .Select(s => new { City = s.Split(",")[0], State = s.Split(",")[1] })
    .OrderBy(s => s.State).ThenBy(s => s.City).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that neither states nor cities are unique keys, I would recommend constructing a list containing pairs of strings (which can be implemented as lists). First, you could sort based on the first string, then, you could sort a subset, EG a given state, by the cities contained within.